# Mapping over sublists in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, list-manipulation

I know that the map function takes each element of a list (a sequence) and applies a function to it.  Recursively (and without respect to termination conditions, etc)

```
map(s, f) = f(s.head) :: map(s.tail, f)
```

I am looking for a function that does something like

```
foo(s, f) = f(s) :: map(s.tail, f).
```

So a 'mapper' where the mapping function gets called on sublists and not individual elements.  In lisp terms, I'm looking for a maplist, as opposed to a mapcar.  Does something like this exist, or do I have to roll my own (or use recursion)?

Alternatively, I'd take a function that takes as input a sequence and returns a sequence of mid-to-end subsequences, ie

```
bar(s, f) = s :: bar(s.tail, f)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired input and output? I'm having trouble following.

Comment: I don't know answer to this question, but if you have a need for advanced types and functions, see Scalaz library: http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/* This approach defines mapList in terms of another useful method called tails. Like Daniel, I'll put it in an implicit extension to List, but that's purely a matter of taste */

```
implicit def richerList[A](list : List[A]) = new {
```

/* Here's a method called tails which returns each  possible tail in the list.  It is tail recursive so it won't blow up on large lists.  Note that it differs slightly from a Haskell function of the same name.  The Haskell version always adds an empty list on to the result */

```
  def tails : List[List[A]] = {
    def loop(ls : List[A], accum : List[List[A]]) : List[List[A]] = ls match {
      case _ :: tail => loop(tail, ls :: accum)
      case _ => accum
    }

    loop(list, Nil).reverse
  }
```

/* This is what using tails looks like

```
scala> "abc".toList.tails
res0: List[List[Char]] = List(List(a, b, c), List(b, c), List(c))
```

*/

/* Now we can define mapList based on tails */

```
  def mapList[B](f : List[A] => B) = tails map f
}
```

/* And this is what using mapList looks like

```
scala> "abc".toList mapList (_.reverse.mkString)
res1: List[String] = List(cba, cb, c)
```

*/

Answer (score 2):

You've basically defined what you're looking for in pseudocode - so it's easy to add such a method to a Scala list using implicit conversions:

```
object ExtendedList{
  implicit def List2ExtendedList[A](l:List[A])=new ExtendedList(l)
}
class ExtendedList[A](l:List[A]){
  import ExtendedList._
  def mapList[B](f:List[A]=>B):List[B]=l.length match {
    case 0 => List()
    case _ => f(l)::l.tail.mapList(f)
  }
}

object Test extends Application{
  import ExtendedList._
  val test = List(5,4,3,2,1)
  assert(List(15,10,6,3,1)==test.mapList{l=>(0/:l){_+_}})
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: It's O(n) to get the length of a list and your mapList does it n times, for O(n^2) cost.    Run this on a large list and you'll be waiting awhile :-)

Comment: The reason I asked is that I'm new to Scala and wanted to know if there was a built-in canonical function (to make my code more readable to others).  Alternatively, I wanted to hear "don't do that, the scala way of doing it is ___"

Comment: Yup, I acknowledge using .length is bad - should have thought about it more!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is close, but you should *never* use `List#length` unless absolutely necessary.  In particular, it makes his solution *O(n^2)* when the problem is inherantly *O(n)*.  Here's a cleaned-up version:

```
implicit def addListSyntax[A](list: List[A]) = new {
  def mapList[B](f: List[A]=>B) = {
    // use inner function to avoid repeated conversions
    def loop(list: List[A]): List[B] = list match {
      case ls @ (_ :: tail) => f(ls) :: loop(tail)
      case Nil => Nil
    }

    loop(list)
  }
}
```

And, to answer your original question: no, there is no way to do this using standard utility methods.  I'm actually a bit curious as to why you would want something like this...

Comment: Be careful here since this version is not tail recursive.  Large lists will cause stack explosion.

Comment: Indeed, that's a huge mistake.

Comment: I have a list of sorted timestamps, and I need to map over things like

-  each timestamp and the y prior timestamps
-  each timestamp, together with all the timestamps for x minutes preceding it.

Again, I know exactly how to code it up in multiple ways (by defining my own mapList, imperatively, using map and then filter inside to generate history, etc) but I wanted to find out how to do this cleanly and the Scala way.